# Inheritance with Hibernate 

Tags: sql, sql-server, inheritance

I need some advice on modelling my data tables. I need to apply inheritance hierarchy on my tables using SQL Server and Hibernate. Could anyone show me a basic example? It could be a tutorial on website too.

Cheers...

Comment: Inheritance and relational don't normally go well together. You *normalise* when designing databases.

Comment: You can't do it in MS SQL, but you can use a framework like Hibernate (or NHibernate) that does the inheritance work for you.  Essentially inheritance in a database is really just a one to one relationship between the Super class table and the sub class table.

Comment: I am going to use hibernate as well. I have got no idea how I will achieve this!

Comment: @Zoidberg: Multi level inheritence which is supported by Hibernate (or Nhibernate) requires tables to be structured in a conceptual hierarchy as shown by @Magnus.

Comment: here's some documentation which i used while creating a hierarchy http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set up the tables so that the derived table shares primary key with base table.

[image]

Comment: Could sharing primary keys with a base table have a negative impact on performance?

Comment: No, by default primary keys are set up as clustered indices. So a join on those two would be very optimized.

Comment: Do you think I can also integrate this model with hibernate?

Comment: I'm sorry but I haven't used Hibernate

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL Server isn't an object-orientated database, it is a relational database.  It sounds like you should be using views over your base tables rather than duplicating columns.

Duplicating columns is unnecessary and would no doubt impact performance and maintenance would become a nightmare.

Maybe edit your question to include more details on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hey there! Yes ms sql is not object oriented, but I need to have a base table. I have got a table Target and this target could be an organization or a person. It is not possible to have them in a common table I somehow need to keep them in separate tables. Could sharing primary keys with a base table have a negative impact on performance? Thanks for the reply...

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to duplicate attributes in child tables and make parent table as VIEW (that selects by common attributes from all children).

```
CREATE VIEW Parent
AS 
SELECT ID, Name FROM Child1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Name FROM Child2 ...
```

The problem could be with ID that should be unique through all the child tables (using GUIDs is preferrable)